# Multiple join with one group by

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I need to join and fetch all data from 3 tables and need to group it using a particular tables field name.Am using codeigniter and sql server

my query:

```
$this->db->select('table1.*,table2.*,table3.*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->join('table3','table1.sid = table3.sid');
$this->db->group_by('table1.field_name');
```

Is it possible?

Am getting this error:

fieldname is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this in model**

```
public function anyfunction($table3_id)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('table1'); 
            $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.table2_id=table2.id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('table3', 'table3.table1_id=table1.table1_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where('table3.table1_id',$table3id);
            $this->db->order_by('table3.field_name','asc');         
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            if($query->num_rows() != 0)
            {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

*i hope it will work for you...*

Comment: this works, once again thank you so much , may i know the reason on this, what was wrong in my query why didnt work..if you are so kind please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you do a Group By in SQL Server, the columns you are permitted to include in your Select statement are limited to the columns in your Group By clause, plus a constant or an aggregate function. So you could do this:

```
Select Table1.field_name, Count(*) as ColumnCount
From Table1
Group By Table1.field_name
```

But you cannot include any other columns from Table1 unless they are in the Group BY.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So we need to specify all columns in select query in group by of we user group by.Is this strategy same in mysql?

Comment: I cannot speak to MySql. You should include a MySql tag in your question so that someone could possibly address this for MySql.

Comment: Sorry, So we need to specify all columns in select query in group by of we user group by?

Comment: @youv - Yes you would but it wouldn't make any sense to do that. You can't possibly want to aggregate on every column in every table. It sounds to me like you don't really have a good understanding of what Group By does and when / why you would want to use it.

Comment: Group by is some thing to group records based on aparticular field name right?I can do this when i use query without joins.My doubt is, when ever i tried to group by using a field am getting the error i have mentioned, i dont know the reason